# Did Sidious ever engineer an army of dark side spies?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, S2E3 *Children of the Force*, Sidious plans to kidnap Force sensitive children to create an army of dark side spies:

> The natural talent these children possess is too great to be wasted by the Jedi.
>   I foresee an army of Force-talented spies in my service, trained in the dark side to peer into every corner of the galaxy from afar. And my enemies would be helpless against such vision.

In the episode his plan is foiled. The children are saved and the holocron with the names and locations of the children is recovered.

However immediately after the Clone Wars, Sidious has no real resistance to stop him picking up this plan again.

My question is, **does Sidious ever create an army of dark side spies as he planned in *Children of the Force*?**

Answer (score 6):

Sort of, in Star Wars Rebels we often meet 'Inquisitors' who are dark-side adepts that often are tasked to hunt down jedi that escaped. There is an episode where they attempt to steal force-sensitive babies. They aren't really spies in the traditional sense though, I figure force-sensitives are too valuable for that. [Wookieepedia link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitorius)

In Legends, there are also the Emperor's Hands such as Mara Jade. [Wookieepedia link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Hand)

Answer (score 2):

Currently in Canon there are two Dark Side organizations, Sith and Inquisitors, both serving Empire. There are also individuals like Maul and remnants of Nightsister clan like [Shelish](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shelish) and [Deathstick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deathstick), but they don't serve Palpatine.

In Legends, there was also Secret Order of the Emperor, also known as [Prophets of the Dark Side](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Prophets_of_the_Dark_Side) and Dark side users like [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek) and his clones, plus Force sensitive [Emperor's Hands](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Hand). It is quite possible some of those ideas will be reused in new Canon, because after defeat of Inquisitors Empire lacks Force users on their side (Vader cannot be everywhere any time) . So, it is quite possible some of them will be resurrected.